# WordPress plugin settings not saving and getting redirected to /wp-admin/options.php (which generates a 404) on submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress using https://github.com/nadeem-khan/WordPress-Plugin-Template as a starter template.

This is my settings class file named 'class-xyz.php':

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    exit;

class Xyz_Settings {

    /**
     * The single instance of Xyz_Settings.
     * @var     object
     * @access  private
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    private static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * The main plugin object.
     * @var     object
     * @access  public
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public $parent = null;

    /**
     * Prefix for plugin settings.
     * @var     string
     * @access  public
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public $base = '';

    /**
     * Available settings for plugin.
     * @var     array
     * @access  public
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public $settings = array();

    public function __construct($parent) {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        $this->base = 'xyzsms_';

        // Initialise settings
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'init_settings'));

        // Register plugin settings
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'register_settings'));

        // Add settings page to menu
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_menu_item'));

        // Add settings link to plugins page
        add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename($this->parent->file), array($this, 'add_settings_link'));
    }

    /**
     * Initialise settings
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_settings() {
        $this->settings = $this->settings_fields();
    }

    /**
     * Add settings page to admin menu
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_menu_item() {
        $page = add_options_page(__('XYZ Settings', 'xyz-template'), __('XYZ Settings', 'xyz-template'), 'manage_options', 'xyz_template_settings', array($this, 'settings_page'));
        add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page, array($this, 'settings_assets'));
    }

    /**
     * Load settings JS & CSS
     * @return void
     */
    public function settings_assets() {

        // We're including the farbtastic script & styles here because they're needed for the colour picker
        // If you're not including a colour picker field then you can leave these calls out as well as the farbtastic dependency for the wpt-admin-js script below
        wp_enqueue_style('farbtastic');
        wp_enqueue_script('farbtastic');

        // We're including the WP media scripts here because they're needed for the image upload field
        // If you're not including an image upload then you can leave this function call out
        wp_enqueue_media();

        wp_register_script($this->parent->_token . '-settings-js', $this->parent->assets_url . 'js/settings' . $this->parent->script_suffix . '.js', array('farbtastic', 'jquery'), '1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_script($this->parent->_token . '-settings-js');
    }

    /**
     * Add settings link to plugin list table
     * @param  array $links Existing links
     * @return array        Modified links
     */
    public function add_settings_link($links) {
        $settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=xyz_template_settings">' . __('Settings', 'xyz-template') . '</a>';
        array_push($links, $settings_link);
        return $links;
    }

    /**
     * Build settings fields
     * @return array Fields to be displayed on settings page
     */
    private function settings_fields() {
        $settings['social-bar-position'] = array(
            'title' => __('Bar Position', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'xyz_position',
                    'label' => __('Position', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'description' => __('Select the position', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'radio',
                    'options' => array('left' => 'Left', 'right' => 'Right'),
                    'default' => 'left'
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'xyz_margin_top',
                    'label' => __('Bar Margin Top', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'description' => __('Define the margin top', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'placeholder' => __('Enter margin.', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'default' => '200px'
                )
            )
        );
        $settings['social-networks-bar'] = array(
            'title' => __('Social Networks', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'xyz_networks',
                    'label' => __('Social', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'description' => __('Select social.', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'checkbox_multi',
                    'options' => array(
                        'facebook' => 'Facebook'
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $settings['links-bar'] = array(
            'title' => __('Links', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'description' => __('Enter the Urls for all the selected social networks:', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'facebook_url',
                    'label' => __('Facebook URL', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'description' => __('Enter the URL for Facebook.', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'placeholder' => __('Enter Facebook URL', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'default' => ''
                )
            )
        );

        $settings['custom-classes-bar'] = array(
            'title' => __('Custom Classes', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'description' => __('Add custom classes in the main parent container of the bar (will affect shortcodes as well):', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'xyz_custom_class',
                    'label' => __('Add Custom Classes in the Bar Parent Container'),
                    'description' => __('Add your own custom CSS class (like customclass1 customclass2). Leave empty if default styling is desired.', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'default' => '',
                    'placeholder' => __('Add custom classes like .custom_class1 .custom_class2 .custom_class3 to the main container of the social bar.', 'xyz-plugin-bar')
                )
            )
        );

        $settings['social-bar-custom-colors'] = array(
            'title' => __('Bar Icons Colors', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'description' => __('Select the colors', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'bar_facebook_icon_custom_color',
                    'label' => __('Facebook Icon Color', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'description' => __('Default color: #FEFEFE ', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'color',
                    'default' => '#FEFEFE'
                )
            )
        );


        $settings['add-custom-css-bar'] = array(
            'title' => __('Add CSS', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'label' => __('Add CSS', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'description' => __('Paste your CSS', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'xyz_add_custom_css',
                    'label' => __('Custom CSS', 'wordpress'),
                    'description' => __('Do not style', 'xyz-plugin-bar'),
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'default' => '',
                    'placeholder' => __('Do not style .', 'xyz-plugin-bar')
                )
            )
        );

        $settings = apply_filters('xyz_fields', $settings);

        return $settings;
    }

    /**
     * Register plugin settings
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_settings() {
        if (is_array($this->settings)) {
            foreach ($this->settings as $section => $data) {

                // Add section to page
                add_settings_section($section, $data['title'], array($this, 'settings_section'), 'xyz_template_settings');

                foreach ($data['fields'] as $field) {

                    // Validation callback for field
                    $validation = '';
                    if (isset($field['callback'])) {
                        $validation = $field['callback'];
                    }

                    // Register field
                    $option_name = $this->base . $field['id'];
                    register_setting('xyz_template_settings', $option_name, $validation);

                    // Add field to page
                    add_settings_field($field['id'], $field['label'], array($this, 'display_field'), 'xyz_template_settings', $section, array('field' => $field));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function settings_section($section) {
        $html = '<p> ' . $this->settings[$section['id']]['description'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        echo $html;
    }

    /**
     * Generate HTML for displaying fields
     * @param  array $args Field data
     * @return void
     */
    public function display_field($args) {

        $field = $args['field'];

        $html = '';

        $option_name = $this->base . $field['id'];
        $option = get_option($option_name);

        $data = '';
        if (isset($field['default'])) {
            $data = $field['default'];
            if ($option) {
                $data = $option;
            }
        }

        switch ($field['type']) {

            case 'text':
            case 'password':
            case 'number':
                $html .= '<input id="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '" type="' . $field['type'] . '" name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr($field['placeholder']) . '" value="' . $data . '"/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case 'text_secret':
                $html .= '<input id="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '" type="text" name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr($field['placeholder']) . '" value=""/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case 'textarea':
                $html .= '<textarea id="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '" rows="5" cols="50" name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr($field['placeholder']) . '">' . $data . '</textarea><br/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case 'checkbox':
                $checked = '';
                if ($option && 'on' == $option) {
                    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                }
                $html .= '<input id="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '" type="' . $field['type'] . '" name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '" ' . $checked . '/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case 'checkbox_multi':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $k => $v) {
                    $checked = false;
                    if (in_array($k, $data)) {
                        $checked = true;
                    }
                    $html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr($field['id'] . '_' . $k) . '"><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($checked, true, false) . ' name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr($k) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field['id'] . '_' . $k) . '" /> ' . $v . '</label> ';
                }
                break;

            case 'radio':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $k => $v) {
                    $checked = false;
                    if ($k == $data) {
                        $checked = true;
                    }
                    $html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr($field['id'] . '_' . $k) . '"><input type="radio" ' . checked($checked, true, false) . ' name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '" value="' . esc_attr($k) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field['id'] . '_' . $k) . '" /> ' . $v . '</label> ';
                }
                break;

            case 'select':
                $html .= '<select name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $k => $v) {
                    $selected = false;
                    if ($k == $data) {
                        $selected = true;
                    }
                    $html .= '<option ' . selected($selected, true, false) . ' value="' . esc_attr($k) . '">' . $v . '</option>';
                }
                $html .= '</select> ';
                break;

            case 'select_multi':
                $html .= '<select name="' . esc_attr($option_name) . '[]" id="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '" multiple="multiple">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $k => $v) {
                    $selected = false;
                    if (in_array($k, $data)) {
                        $selected = true;
                    }
                    $html .= '<option ' . selected($selected, true, false) . ' value="' . esc_attr($k) . '" />' . $v . '</label> ';
                }
                $html .= '</select> ';
                break;

            case 'image':
                $image_thumb = '';
                if ($data) {
                    $image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($data);
                }
                $html .= '<img id="' . $option_name . '_preview" class="image_preview" src="' . $image_thumb . '" /><br/>' . "\n";
                $html .= '<input id="' . $option_name . '_button" type="button" data-uploader_title="' . __('Upload an image', 'xyz-template') . '" data-uploader_button_text="' . __('Use image', 'xyz-template') . '" class="image_upload_button button" value="' . __('Upload new image', 'xyz-template') . '" />' . "\n";
                $html .= '<input id="' . $option_name . '_delete" type="button" class="image_delete_button button" value="' . __('Remove image', 'xyz-template') . '" />' . "\n";
                $html .= '<input id="' . $option_name . '" class="image_data_field" type="hidden" name="' . $option_name . '" value="' . $data . '"/><br/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case 'color':
                ?><div class="color-picker" style="position:relative;">
                    <input type="text" name="<?php esc_attr_e($option_name); ?>" class="color" value="<?php esc_attr_e($data); ?>" />
                    <div style="position:absolute;background:#FFF;z-index:99;border-radius:100%;" class="colorpicker"></div>
                </div>
                <?php
                break;
        }

        switch ($field['type']) {

            case 'checkbox_multi':
            case 'radio':
            case 'select_multi':
                $html .= '<br/><span class="description">' . $field['description'] . '</span>';
                break;

            default:
                $html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr($field['id']) . '"><span class="description">' . $field['description'] . '</span></label>' . "\n";
                break;
        }

        echo $html;
    }

    /**
     * Validate individual settings field
     * @param  string $data Inputted value
     * @return string       Validated value
     */
    public function validate_field($data) {
        if ($data && strlen($data) > 0 && $data != '') {
            $data = urlencode(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $data)));
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Load settings page content
     * @return void
     */
    public function settings_page() {

        // Build page HTML
        $html = '<div class="wrap" id="xyz_settings">' . "\n";
        $html .= '<h2>' . __('XYZ Settings', 'xyz-template') . '</h2>' . "\n";
        $html .= '<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">' . "\n";

        // Setup navigation
        $html .= '<ul id="settings-sections" class="subsubsub hide-if-no-js">' . "\n";
        $html .= '<li><a class="tab all current" href="#all">' . __('All', 'xyz-template') . '</a></li>' . "\n";

        foreach ($this->settings as $section => $data) {
            $html .= '<li>| <a class="tab" href="#' . $section . '">' . $data['title'] . '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }

        $html .= '</ul>' . "\n";

        $html .= '<div class="clear"></div>' . "\n";

        // Get settings fields
        ob_start();
        settings_fields('xyz_template_settings');
        do_settings_sections('xyz_template_settings');
        $html .= ob_get_clean();

        $html .= '<p class="submit">' . "\n";
        $html .= '<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="' . esc_attr(__('Save Settings', 'xyz-template')) . '" />' . "\n";
        $html .= '</p>' . "\n";
        $html .= '</form>' . "\n";
        $html .= '</div>' . "\n";

        echo $html;
    }

    /**
     * Main Xyz_Settings Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of Xyz_Settings is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @static
     * @see Xyz()
     * @return Main Xyz_Settings instance
     */
    public static function instance($parent) {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new self($parent);
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

// End instance()

    /**
     * Cloning is forbidden.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __clone() {
        _doing_it_wrong(__FUNCTION__, __('Cheatin&#8217; huh?'), $this->parent->_version);
    }

// End __clone()

    /**
     * Unserializing instances of this class is forbidden.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __wakeup() {
        _doing_it_wrong(__FUNCTION__, __('Cheatin&#8217; huh?'), $this->parent->_version);
    }

// End __wakeup()
}
```

All the settings fields are displayed properly but as soon as the submit button is pressed 404 is generated and no settings get saved. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:** Here's how the initialize Xyz_Settings class is initialized in another file:

```
function Xyz_bar_init () {
    $instance = Xyz_bar::instance( __FILE__, '1.0.0' );
    if( is_null( $instance->settings ) ) {
        $instance->settings = Xyz_Settings::instance( $instance );
    }
    return $instance;
}

Xyz_bar_init();
```

**UPDATE(2):** I have activated a very trimmed down version of my own plugin with only 2-3 settings options and it seems to work perfectly (as values are getting saved/retrieved in the db correctly). Can the shear number of setting options be causing the issue with the full fledge plugin that has over 200 options (please note that I am using a shared hosting with limited resources)?

Comment: Under settings_page function, change form action to <?php echo admin_url( "options-general.php?page=xyz_template_settings" ); ?>

Comment: @Amit it didn't help and I still get a 404

Comment: It's working on my end. How are you using the `Xyz_Settings` class? Can you add the code that initializes the `Xyz_Settings` instance? Are you using WordPress 4.1? What version of PHP are you using? What browser are you getting the error in?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I have added the initialize code for the xyz_Settings class. My php version is 5.3.28 and yes its WordPress 4.1. I get this error on Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m.

Comment: Does `Xyz_bar_init` get called on the 404 page? Does it work if you do  `require_once( __DIR__ . '/class-xyz.php' );
Xyz_Settings::instance();`?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the class file is already included and using Xyz_Settings::instance(); right after the require_once statement also didn't help. The problem is very confusing. On my localhost development WordPress setup, no 404 is generated but the options aren't saved in the database either.

Comment: @nk-47 I wonder if you can upload your current plugin version to github - since it's not clear what's your exact plugin setup.

Comment: @birgire The plugin is not intended to be open source, that is the reason I cannot share the complete code on GitHub. However, I can share the complete plugin settings related code if you could mail me at 'nadeem.khan@chillopedia.com'

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Please check my Update(2) and suggest how to confirm if its caused by limited hosting resources.

Comment: It's possible I suppose, but I would expect you would get a different error message than 404. Can you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We don't need to whole plugin, just enough to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are saving a large number of options, make sure you don't saturate the `max_input_vars` limit, that was introduced in PHP 5.3.9 to limit the number of accepted input variables - from the PHP docs:

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET,
>   $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive
>   mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash
>   collisions.

You should be able to modify this value to your needs in `php.ini`.

Also remember to check your error logs.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed with the huge number of settings I was trying to save. I have now used jQuery to hide all the unused settings based on user input before submitting the settings form which has resolved my issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved @nk-47. Maybe you could also try to add more  settings pages, to limit the number of input variables sent on form submissions?

Comment: As its a social networks related plugin therefore all options have to be on a single settings page. Now with jQuery I am only displaying and submitting options for social networks that the user selects (thus reducing the overall number of options that are POSTed on form submission).

Comment: ps: I guess one could also count the selected form inputs with jQuery and make sure it's less than `<?php echo ini_get( 'max_input_vars' ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I have Make changes in this file and now post are showing :- class-wordpress-plugin-template-post_type.php
your code :-

```
// Post type name and labels
        $this->post_type = 'post_type';
        $this->plural = _x( 'Posts', 'post type general name' , 'wordpress-plugin-template' );
        $this->single = _x( 'Post', 'post type singular name' , 'wordpress-plugin-template' );
```

My code :-

```
// Post type name and labels
        $this->post_type = 'post_type1'; // change your value here
        $this->plural = _x( 'Your Posts', 'post type general name' , 'wordpress-plugin-template' );
        $this->single = _x( 'Post', 'post type singular name' , 'wordpress-plugin-template' );
```

Comment: I am not using the custom post type code present in the starter plugin at all. I have removed that portion from my plugin.

Comment: Have you changed wp_options key in your plugin.? Your setting is working  on my end.

Comment: Please clearify and guide a bit. What wp_options 'key'?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/permalinks and simply save your setting again, no need to change anything. 9 out of 10 this will fix the 404 problem after adding custom settings (same for custom templates).

You can also add '`flush_rewrite_rules();`' at the end of your construct function to avoid this step.

[Edit]
Ok, now that out the way... your forms action points to simply "options.php". This means your plugin will look in the plugin or root folder for options.php. It should be `site_url()."/wp-admin/options.php"`.

Comment: It didn't help. I am still redirected to /wp-admin/options.php (which generates a 404) on saving the plugin's settings.

Comment: Even after adding '$html .= "<form method='post' action='" . site_url() . "/wp-admin/options.php' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>" . "\n";' I am still redirected to http://example.com/wp-admin/options.php which in turn throws a 404 error.

Comment: If you just type in "example.com/wp-admin/options.php" with no apramaters in your browsers URL bar, does is still give you a 404 error?

Comment: No it opens up "All Settings" page without any issues

Comment: Ok, one thing I did notice is the ob_start and ob_get_clean. These messed me around before, so I don't use them. Seems odd I know, but take out those two lines and see if you get the same issue. Another thing to try is change your action method to GET (just for now), which may help you spot a problem in the url when you get the 404 error.